# Can we get InfoSec Ex hoodies?

Tags: discussion, swag

This has probably already been asked and I don't know how possible this is, but... Can we get InfoSec Ex hoodies?

I know StackEx used to have a shop a long time ago and it closed due to the reasons stated [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store) but since then StackEx must've gained *a lot* of users.

What're your thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure you can get one printed quite easily.

Comment: I think logo licensing on SE would allow you to make your own.

Comment: 'Tis exactly what I did! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange has continued to grow, but there has not been a business case yet to reopen the shop.

That said, swag for Sec.SE does exist, and mods do take swag to various security conferences each year to give out, and the are occasional opportunities to win swag.

So far there hasn't been a Sec.SE hoodie (trust me, I would have found out) but there are t-shirts, pens, torches, stickers etc. and I have given some out at B-Sides in Edinburgh, Glasgow and San Francisco, Infosec, and a few other conferences.

Comment: That's the same general idea I got from Forest in the DMZ. As for the hoodie, I love hoodies so much! :D To be honest, it will only cost me £30~ to get one printed myself so I might just do that, haha! Thank you Rory.

Comment: Do you have the link to request swag to give out at conferences?